# Adding custom field to OpenCart admin with VQmod

Tags: opencart, vqmod

Trying to add a short description field to the category pages in OpenCart back office. Have multiple instances of VQmod XML working fine in controllers and models but trying to use the below to add the field to the category page appears to be doing nothing at all. Nothing gets added/replaced at all in the category_form.tpl.

```
<!-- This adds the short description field to the admin category page -->
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_short_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>           
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

There is clearly a better approach to this as I don't think I should be trying to replace all this code here but if I anyone could kindly check that code over and point out where I've gone wrong, that would be great. Thanks.

## Update

My XML code is wrapped in `<modification>` `</modification>` by the way....

I have tried using offset and referred to the VQmod documentation but still am unable to get this right...

I have tried:-

```
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace" offset="1"><![CDATA[<td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_short_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>
                <td><textarea name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" id="description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>]]></add>  
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 1):

First whole code should be wrapped in

```
<modification>
    <file ...>
        ....
    </file>
</modification>
```

Second you can't search multiple lines you can search particular line and then use `offset` attribute

for your case use

```
<search position="replace" offset="1"><![CDATA[ <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?></td>]]></search>
```

refer to [vQmod documentation](http://vqmod.com).

Comment: I had tried using offset and referred to documentation to no avail, your suggestion still results in the search not to be found. (Have updated my question with details). Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I've found the issue was actually due to another place in the XML file that was causing my replace specified above not to run. Useless as ever error log. Thanks for your assistance though.